# Conflict between diffcoeff and mhchem

Tags: errors, mhchem, compilation-error, diffcoeff

I notice recently a conflict between the packages diffcoeff and mhchem. 
For this file :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\printFileList
Test
\end{document}
```

the .log file is

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=latex 2018.10.24)  24 OCT 2018 20:55
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Test.tex
(./Test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2018/04/06 v1.3b Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def
File: t1enc.def 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding T1 on input line 48.
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/diffcoeff/diffcoeff.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2018-10-19 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2018-10-19 L3 programming layer (code)
\c_max_int=\count88
\l_tmpa_int=\count89
\l_tmpb_int=\count90
\g_tmpa_int=\count91
\g_tmpb_int=\count92
\g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count93
\c_log_iow=\count94
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count95
\l__iow_line_target_int=\count96
\l__iow_one_indent_int=\count97
\l__iow_indent_int=\count98
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip43
\c_max_skip=\skip44
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
\l_keys_choice_int=\count99
\l__intarray_loop_int=\count100
\c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen109
\g__intarray_font_int=\count101
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count102
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count109
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count110
\c__kernel_randint_max_int=\count111
\g__fp_array_int=\count112
\l__fp_array_loop_int=\count113
\l__sort_length_int=\count114
\l__sort_min_int=\count115
\l__sort_top_int=\count116
\l__sort_max_int=\count117
\l__sort_true_max_int=\count118
\l__sort_block_int=\count119
\l__sort_begin_int=\count120
\l__sort_end_int=\count121
\l__sort_A_int=\count122
\l__sort_B_int=\count123
\l__sort_C_int=\count124
\l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count125
\l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count126
\l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count127
\l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count128
\l__regex_internal_a_int=\count129
\l__regex_internal_b_int=\count130
\l__regex_internal_c_int=\count131
\l__regex_balance_int=\count132
\l__regex_group_level_int=\count133
\l__regex_mode_int=\count134
\c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count135
\c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count136
\l__regex_catcodes_int=\count137
\l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count138
\c__regex_catcode_D_int=\count139
\c__regex_catcode_S_int=\count140
\c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count141
\c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count142
\c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count143
\c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count144
\l__regex_show_lines_int=\count145
\l__regex_min_state_int=\count146
\l__regex_max_state_int=\count147
\l__regex_left_state_int=\count148
\l__regex_right_state_int=\count149
\l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count150
\l__regex_min_pos_int=\count151
\l__regex_max_pos_int=\count152
\l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count153
\l__regex_start_pos_int=\count154
\l__regex_success_pos_int=\count155
\l__regex_curr_char_int=\count156
\l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count157
\l__regex_last_char_int=\count158
\l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count159
\l__regex_curr_state_int=\count160
\l__regex_step_int=\count161
\l__regex_min_active_int=\count162
\l__regex_max_active_int=\count163
\l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count164
\l__regex_match_count_int=\count165
\l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count166
\l__regex_submatch_int=\count167
\l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count168
\g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count169
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen110
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen111
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen112
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen113
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen114
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen115
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen116
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen117
\l__box_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box32
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen118
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen119
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen120
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen121
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen122
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen123
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen124
\c_empty_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box34
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box36
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box40
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen125
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen127
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen133
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen134
\l__seq_internal_a_int=\count170
\l__seq_internal_b_int=\count171
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3dvips.def
File: l3dvips.def 2018-10-19 v L3 Experimental driver: dvips
\g__driver_pdf_object_int=\count172
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2018-10-17 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count173
\g__xparse_grabber_int=\count174
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count175
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count176
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count177
)
Package: diffcoeff 2016/06/27 v1.0 Write differential coefficients easily.
\l__diffco_curr_tok_int=\count178
\l__diffco_curr_state_int=\count179
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mhchem/mhchem.sty
Package: mhchem 2018/06/22 v4.08 for typesetting chemical formulae

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
Package: l3keys2e 2018-10-17 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
) (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty
Package: calc 2017/05/25 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count180
\calc@Bcount=\count181
\calc@Adimen=\dimen135
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen136
\calc@Askip=\skip49
\calc@Bskip=\skip50
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 80.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 81.
\calc@Ccount=\count182
\calc@Cskip=\skip51
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip52

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\ex@=\dimen137
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen138
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count183
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 213.
\uproot@=\count184
\leftroot@=\count185
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 375.
\classnum@=\count186
\DOTSCASE@=\count187
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 472.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 475.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 596.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box41
\strutbox@=\box42
\big@size=\dimen139
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 712.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 713.
\macc@depth=\count188
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count189
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count190
\dspbrk@lvl=\count191
\tag@help=\toks17
\row@=\count192
\column@=\count193
\maxfields@=\count194
\andhelp@=\toks18
\eqnshift@=\dimen140
\alignsep@=\dimen141
\tagshift@=\dimen142
\tagwidth@=\dimen143
\totwidth@=\dimen144
\lineht@=\dimen145
\@envbody=\toks19
\multlinegap=\skip53
\multlinetaggap=\skip54
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks20
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2817.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2818.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/chemgreek/chemgreek.sty
Package: chemgreek 2016/12/20 v1.1 interfaceforuprightgreeklettersforuseinchemi
stry (CN)
\l__chemgreek_tmpa_int=\count195
\g__chemgreek_tmpa_int=\count196
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: dvips.def on input line 99.

(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def
File: dvips.def 2017/06/20 v3.1d Graphics/color driver for dvips
))
\l__mhchem_ce_distanceFromLastComma_int=\count197
\__mhchem_arrow_extPgfLength_skip=\skip55
\mhchem@minispace@tmp=\skip56
\mhchem@minibackspace@tmp=\skip57
\mhchem@bondwidth=\skip58
\mhchem@bondheight=\skip59
\mhchem@smallbondwidth@tmpA=\skip60
\mhchem@smallbondwidth@tmpB=\skip61
\mhchem@smallbondwidth=\skip62
\mhchem@bondtmp@minussidebearingleft=\skip63
\mhchem@bondtmp@minussidebearingright=\skip64
\l__mhchem_option_version_int=\count198
\mhchem@option@minusmathsidebearingleft=\dimen146
\mhchem@option@minusmathsidebearingright=\dimen147
\mhchem@option@minustextsidebearingleft=\dimen148
\mhchem@option@minustextsidebearingright=\dimen149
)
(./Test.aux)
\openout1 = `Test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.


! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.7 \begin{document}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Argument of \__iow_wrap_break_none:w has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.7 \begin{document}

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \__iow_wrap_break_none:w was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.7 \begin{document}

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

)
Runaway argument?
76543210\q_stop end \exp_args:NNf \group_end: \iow_log:n {\tl_to_str:N \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \__iow_wrap_end_chunk:w.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> Test.tex

I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Emergency stop.
<*> Test.tex

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 11477 strings out of 492640
 217923 string characters out of 6129336
 271481 words of memory out of 5000000
 15377 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 533400 words of font info for 26 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 41i,1n,63p,344b,275s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue arises as `diffcoeff` sets a macro called `\msg_info_text:n` to

```
\cs_gset:Npn \msg_info_text:n #1  
  { Use~the~order-override~option~to~specify~the~overall~order~of~
      differentiation~(or~use~diffcoeffx.sty). }
```

whereas by default it much shorter *and* generic. It's intended for allowing the *language* of messages to change, nor for use by single packages. (It produces the `Package X Info` text for messages from `expl3`.)

Within the message code of `expl3`, there's an assumption that `\msg_info_text:n` produces something shorter than a whole line. Here, that's no longer the case, and at present there is not a sanity check internally for this issue. I'll add one, and I'll report the issue to the maintainer of `diffcoeff`. For the present, add

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \msg_info_text:n #1 { \__msg_text:nn {#1} { Info } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

after the line loading `diffcoeff`.